# Google oauth client exception on wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-calendar-api, wildfly

I tried to integrate google calendar API with my project. Tested in local environment and it seems work fine. But when I deploy my .ear file on wildfly, it gives me the following error:

Stacktrace :

```
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1) 2021-02-08
 11:26:06.187 ERROR o.s.a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler -
 Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void
 com.xyz.soa.serviceImpl.email.CalendarServiceImpl.createGoogleCalendarEvent(com.xyz.soa.model.EmailInfo)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver$Builder.build(LocalServerReceiver.java:248)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 com.xyz.soa.serviceImpl.email.CalendarServiceImpl.getCredentials(CalendarServiceImpl.java:82)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 com.xyz.soa.serviceImpl.email.CalendarServiceImpl.getCalendar(CalendarServiceImpl.java:89)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 com.xyz.soa.serviceImpl.email.CalendarServiceImpl.createGoogleCalendarEvent(CalendarServiceImpl.java:103)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 2021-02-08
 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)     at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 2021-02-08
 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)     at
 org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 2021-02-08
 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO 
 [stdout] ("async-thread-"1) Caused by:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler
 from [Module "deployment.project-api.war" from Service Module Loader]
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,187 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  at
 org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
 2021-02-08 11:26:06,188 INFO  [stdout] ("async-thread-"1)  ... 16
 common frames omitted
```

Google calendar lib that I have added :

```
 compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.31.0'
compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.31.0'
 compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-calendar', version: 'v3-rev411-1.25.0'
```

From the error I understand that, `LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();` this line is causing problem which is from google-oauth-client(note that, it works on local env.). So I checked my `.ear` package and found these libraries shown in the image. ***Note that, I found two jar files for oauth client***!
[image: google oauth client lib]

Please suggest how do I get rid of this ?

Comment: When you run it locally are you running from an IDE. That would probably ensure the the libraries are in the classpath, but you run it remotely, they are not. Check your packaging

Comment: @jr593, I have added google oauth cliient of v1.31.0. but in my .ear file, I found that one as well as another one version  too: 1.31.2. jar path: `WEB-INF/lib/`

Comment: You are getting NoClassDefFoundError for `com.sun.net.httpserver.HTTPHandler`. Are you sure you have this in your packaged set of libraries?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html

Comment: @Maverick, thanks man. thank you too. I added that and it works now.  Btw, you can add it as answer

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it helped? I have added it ss an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NoClassDefFoundError` for `com.sun.net.httpserver.HTTPHandler`. Are you sure you have [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html) in your packaged set of libraries?

Comment: that was not present in my packaging but I have added it(I thought/read it should be default after jvm6+ versions though)